# error: 'execute_data' undeclared #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element) in php 7.0

Tags: php-internals, php

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L2322

In the above link i used the backtrace function in my extension where I am getting the following error message because of the line EX(prev_execute_data)

> error: 'execute_data' undeclared (first use in this function)
>    #define EX(element)    ((execute_data)->element)
>                             ^
>
> 644:8: note: in expansion of macro 'EX' ptr = EX(prev_execute_data);
>           ^
>
> note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
>   function it appears in                   #define EX(element)
>   ((execute_data)->element)
>                             ^
>
> 644:8: note: in expansion of macro 'EX'   ptr = EX(prev_execute_data);
>           ^
>
> 658:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]    ptr =
>   zend_generator_check_placeholder_frame(ptr);
>          ^
>
> make: *** [zpa.lo] Error 1

Can any one help me in finding the solution for this ?

Comment: ugh, this is probably a question for some mailing list or some community chat of the zend-community? and although the tag "php" might be fitting here ... it's probably wrong to not use a "c" tag as well ... or primarily ... but as i said ... I would go to some developer channel at zend

Comment: How exactly you call this function? Can you show the code of your extension?

Comment: Present i am getting trace after doing some changes in the code but still  i want to know what is the reason 
https://github.com/patrickallaert/php-apm/blob/master/backtrace.c#L72
the above link contains the source 
When i am using EG(current_execute_data) i am not getting the trace part and some php files are not executing and when i use EX(prev_execute_data) it is showing the error